# Confirm and Cancel Button Laravel Sweet Alert

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert

Good Morning:

I am trying to use plugin Sweet Alert in Laravel. 
My problem is, I don´t know the how to put a Alert with Cancel Button and Confirm Button in Controller. 
Reading the documentation, I only found this sentence:

```
Alert::warning('Are you sure?', 'message')->persistent('Close');
```

Also, I trying with:

```
echo '<script>swal({ title: "Are you sure?", text: "name is available, continue save?", type: "warning", showCancelButton: true, confirmButtonColor:"#DD6B55",  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   closeOnConfirm: false }, function(){});</script>';
```

But it not working.

How can I use Sweet Alert in my Controller showing a Cancel Button and Confirm Button?

Thanks

Comment: hi are you using this repo? https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert

Comment: It looks like he's using that. I personally think that library creates more work than necessary. Something so simple like; swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'The product will be added.',
      type: 'info',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, import it!',
      cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancel'
    }) Should work. Just include the https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ scripts and that's it.

Comment: Have you tried this outside of Laravel after including the sweetalert2 scripts in your HTML? Maybe the scripts are not being included.

Comment: it appears he is trying to call from controller itself as he is using echo for that..

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes I am using Sweet-Alert from Github in Laravel 5.4

I can´t show a confir button with de code that give me the documentation. Only can show a Close Button:
->persistent('Close');

I read a way doing it with "echo" in the Controller. However, I am testing and not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert) repo then I insist you to read the docs thoroughly as it is given how generate alerts with proper snippets You are basically looking for [this](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert#custom-view)

> Snippet from the repo itself

**Controller**

Your controller should look like this

```
public function yourfunction()
{
    Alert::warning('Are you sure?', 'message')->persistent('Close');

    return to whatever view    
   //return redirect::home();
}
```

**View**

Inside the view where you are redirecting from the store method you should do something like as given in repo

```
@if (Session::has('sweet_alert.alert'))
    <script>
        swal({
            text: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.text') !!}",
            title: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.title') !!}",
            timer: {!! Session::get('sweet_alert.timer') !!},
            type: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.type') !!}",
            showConfirmButton: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.showConfirmButton') !!}",
            confirmButtonText: "{!! Session::get('sweet_alert.confirmButtonText') !!}",
            confirmButtonColor: "#AEDEF4"

            // more options
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

PS:: I haven't used sweet alerts yet but this repo is cool! it has all you want to know about sweet alerts!

Comment: Hi. I need show a button Confirm and Cancel in the Controller. When a conditional success and before to save.
->persistent('Close');
It is not enough for me.

Comment: but you can use showConfirmButton for that have you tried that??

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You mean that I can use ->persistent('showConfirmButton ') ??

Comment: Ok, thanks! However,  I didn´t see it in the docs. Anyway, I will try it.

Comment: I have added this code from docs bro have a try if you found any difficulty we will try to fix meanwhile if you got what you want then please accept the answer to close this question thanks :)